# How to using Ruby Mail gem to retrieve email using POP3 and oauth2 token for office 365?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, office365, pop3

Currently we are using the mail gem to access our email in outlook.

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3,
    address: "outlook.office365.com",
    port: 995,
    user_name: username,
    password: password,
    enable_ssl: true'
end

all_mails = Mail.all
```

According to Microsoft, they no longer support login with user_name and password for POP3 mail anymore, and now require an oauth_token from oauth2.  I am able to get the token fine, but not sure if there is away to use that token in the mail gem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it up this way

```
auth_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
auth_params = {
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  refresh_token: refresh_token,
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret: client_secret,
  scope: 'https://outlook.office365.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All'
}

auth_response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI(auth_url), auth_params)
auth_data = JSON.parse(auth_response.body)
```